# Terraform Multi Level Maps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm getting errors on "terraform plan" when trying to use a multi-level map. I am unable to use the map in `google_compute_instance` module. My goal is to launch multiple VM's with different properties using a single `google_compute_instance` module. I request you to help me correct my main.tf or suggest me to achieve my goal

Variable.tf

```
variable "instance_config" {
  type    = list(map(string))
  default = []
}
```

.tfvars

```
instance_config = {
  test-vm1 = {
      instance_name  = "test-vm1"
      instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
      instance_type =  "n1-standard-4"
     },

  test-vm2 = {
      instance_name  = "test-vm2"
      instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      instance_type =  "f1-micro"
     }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {

 { for instance_name, instance_type, instance_image in var.instance_config :
  name         = instance_config.instance_name
  machine_type = instance_config.instance_type
  tags         = var.instance_tags
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image =  instance_config.instance_image
    }
  }
 }

  network_interface {
    network = "${var.gcp_network}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for `for_each` is incorrect and your `instance_config` has wrong format. It should be:

```
variable "instance_config" {

  type = map(object({
        instance_name  = string
        instance_image = string
        instance_type  = string
       }))
  
  default = {
    test-vm1 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm1"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
        instance_type =  "n1-standard-4"
       },

    test-vm2 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm2"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        instance_type =  "f1-micro"
       }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {

  for_each     = var.instance_config
   
  name         = each.value.instance_name
  machine_type = each.value.instance_type
  tags         = var.instance_tags

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = each.value.instance_image
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.gcp_network
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton it's working, one last question please, How do I pass these values from `.tfvars` instead of `variables.tf`

Comment: @Eva You separate them as in your question. Just make sure the types are preserved, and is `default = {}`.

Comment: I am still getting any error. I created a new [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063395/terraform-values-from-tfvars-are-not-loading-when-using-multi-level-maps) with the error can you please help me here!

Comment: Stackoverflow didn't allow me to create a new post, so I had to create it in serverfault. Please check and comment on the [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063395/terraform-values-from-tfvars-are-not-loading-when-using-multi-level-maps)